# what is the best between google map API v2, google map API V3 OpenStreetMap for android application?

Tags: android, openstreetmap

i'm developping an android application for tour guide using REST API and Json, so i need to make a map. i don't know what is the best to work with (google map API V2 or API V3 or OpenStreetMap)?? my boss tell me to avoid google map because google can withdraw it at any time.

Comment: If your boss tells you to avoid google map, I suggest you listen.  But you are allowed to cache or store OpenStreetMap maps locally. Your boss *could* also argue that OpenStreetMap isn't 100% complete (but google maps isn't either) and organized by "just a bunch" of volunteers. Essentially: both have drawbacks. But there are already solid Android apps built on OpenStreetMap (waze, mapsme), so technically both are viable options.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google maps v3 is not for Android. And seeing your tags on question, I think it's not an option for you.
As far as Google maps v2 and openStreetMap are concerned, I have always preferred Goole maps because it belongs to same Google Android belongs. So there are (probably) easier integrations and it makes sense to use it especially on Android.
 Besides, the point that "Google can withdraw it any time" doesn't make any sense to me. Think of the things you use on Android and what if "Google withdraws them".
For why openStreetMap is better than Google maps (not from developer's point of view), see this
[Founder: OpenStreetMap Already As Good Or Better Than Google Maps](http://searchengineland.com/founder-openstreetmap-good-better-google-maps-already-192089)

Answer (score 0):

The boss probably told you this, because it is NOT allowed to use the Google API for this purpose because of their terms. See [10.2 d) i)](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

*(d) No Navigation, Autonomous Vehicle Control, or Enterprise Applications. You must not use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications for or in connection with any of the following:
(i) real-time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of a user's sensor-enabled device.*